# Web photo album

Tags: web-apps, photography, web

I'm looking for a photo organizer and viewer that would allow me to publish my photographs on my personal website (running on Linux CentOS Stream 8).  Something like a personal version of Flickr, but fully hosted and controlled by me.

Ideally I would like it to be able to **upload and organize photos directly from the website itself, via a web interface**; otherwise, a Windows desktop program that does so is also acceptable.

It must also support short videos (~30 secs).

Preferably Open Source and/or free.

Here are some [suggestions](https://lifehacker.com/how-can-i-take-control-and-host-my-own-photos-online-1461903693); any personal experience with any of these?

Answer (score 1):

First recommendetion is [`piwigo`](https://www.piwigo.org/), [wikipedia](https://piwigo.org/).
Next [`photonix`](https://photonix.org/).